# How to create a dictionary from a list with a key-value pair of (value, frequency). A way besides for loop?

Tags: python

```
from numpy.random import randint

orig_list = randint(0, 99, 1000)
dictionary = {}

for item in orig_list:
    if not item in dictionary:
        dictionary[item] = 0
    dictionary[item] += 1
```

I know I can loop through the `list` and do `dictionary[item] += 1`, but is there no faster way?

Comment: That sounds like an ideal use for `collections.Counter`.

Comment: You want [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is a specialized dict for counting things. Also, the construct you want for creating it without a for-loop is a ***dict comprehension*** (or ***Counter comprehension***, in this case).